# Reading a value from a map in a template (which is set via an observable)

Tags: angular

My service is returning a Map. Now I want to use one of the values in my template but it won't show and I don't understand why.

I've created an example:

1 value is set via the constructor which is shown, the other 2 via an observable. The first one ('myKey') is shown the other one isn't.

```
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {

    loadTestData(): Observable<Map<string, string>> {
        const testData = new Map<string, string>();
        testData.set('mySecondKey', 'mySecondValue');
        testData.set('myThirdKey', 'myThirdValue');

        return Observable.of(testData);
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <h3>Shown: {{test.get('myKey')}}</h3>
      <h3>Not shown: {{test.get('mySecondKey')}}</h3>
      <h3>Map size: {{test.size}}</h3>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  name:string;
  test: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
    this.test.set('myKey', 'myValue');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.messageService.loadTestData().subscribe(data => {
      this.test = data;
    });

  }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/6mUieUMJTSvekiNxEuU3

Comment: plunk isnt working !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the code is perfectly fine with one exception - missing import of `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';`. Seems like current SystemJS configuration is swallowing the errors.

Here is updated plnkr  - https://plnkr.co/edit/WyQzOos0IOnvRZkzWSRS?p=preview

Comment: Huh.... In my production code I use import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable"; When I use your import it does work! Does this make sense?

Comment: These are different imports :)

`import .... from 'rxjs/Rx';` imports the all rxjs scripts, which is not fine for production.

`import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";` will import only the `Observable` and the `of` operator, which should be also fine in your case 

You can check this article for more details - http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/installation.html

Comment: I see. I will google to see the differences and when to use what. Thanks!

Comment: I one more question: loadTestData is normally a http.get('/mydata') this returns the other Observable. How can I change that?

Comment: I don't get where is the problem with this. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I made another plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/QU85vevc5bBenVeT8hCO?p=preview

Comment: `subscribe` callback will be executed when the `http.get` completes with the response. That said there shouldn't be any difference in how you consume that observable.

The `loadTestData` method should simply return the observable from [http.get](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get).

Comment: In that case I don't understand why this isn't working: https://plnkr.co/edit/QU85vevc5bBenVeT8hCO?p=preview

Comment: `wait` is not defined in the demo. I've modified it to simulate remote call. See the updated demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/bMoRXsxG4hytttSrBbg4?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not waiting for the subscribed data abd trying to render it before the value arrives.Modify your code as follow

In your component declare a boolean variable

```
private dataAvailable:boolean=false;
```

And toggle the value once the data is available

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.messageService.loadTestData().subscribe(data => {
      this.test = data;
this.dataAvailable=true;

    });

  }
```

and in the template ,wait for the value

```
<div *ngIf="dataAvailable">
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <h3>Shown: {{test.get('myKey')}}</h3>
      <h3>Not shown: {{test.get('mySecondKey')}}</h3>
      <h3>Map size: {{test.size}}</h3>
    </div>
```

It should do the trick.You can as well use async pipe for achieving the same .You can find the docs [here](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).Hope it helps

Comment: I tried the async pipe but no luck. Tried it with {{test.get('mySecondKey') | async}}. Your example doesn't work either.